# The ! and the && operators Java

Tags: java, logical-operators

Ok so, I was working on a program and I ran into a little problem/question.

E.g.

```
int num1 = 3, int num2 =0;   
while (!num1 == 1 && num2 == 0)
    { 
      ...
    }
```

Does the `!` apply to the whole statment in, or only to the part before `&&`?

Comment: Learn from this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: `!num1 == 1` This code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

The `!` part actually only applies to the `num1` integer (Which is surely not what you want), not even the `num1 == 1` part.

So your expression is basically,

```
if (((!num1) == 1) && (num2 == 0)) {
```

Comment: To clarify, `! num1` is invalid, so the code won't compile, with or without those parenthesis. You can't do boolean *"not"* on a number in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` is applied before the `&&` according to the Java [order of operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), so the `!` only applies to the part before the `&&`.

Comment: It's applied before `==` too, so it won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use IDE such as Eclipse and set Compiler compliance levels to latest Java versions. You will get errors to help you make the right decision.

And if you want to read how precedence works, then follow the official Java reference link here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html